# SendInput does not send the exact amount of pixels I specify

Tags: c++, winapi

I prepare the input buffer like this

```
...
buffer->mi.dx = x;
buffer->mi.dy = y;
buffer->mi.mouseData = 0;
buffer->mi.time = 0;
buffer->mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
buffer->mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE);
SendInput(1, buffer, sizeof(INPUT));
std::cout << "moving " << buffer->mi.dx << "," << buffer->mi.dy << " relative to current position"  << std::endl;
...
```

Here's the output of this code:

```
Current Mouse position: 755,286
moving 0,10 relative to current position
Result: 755,294
```

I need to avoid `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` `dwflag` if possible.

Any ides on why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ides on why this is happening and how can I fix it?

I'm guessing it's mouse-acceleration. This is mentioned in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event

> **Relative mouse motion is subject to the settings for mouse speed and acceleration** level. An end user sets these values using the Mouse application in Control Panel. An application obtains and sets these values with the `SystemParametersInfo` function.

Obviously a workaround is to disable mouse-acceleration, but that's not something you should be doing (and if I ever catch any programs on *my* computer messing with my mouse settings, they find themselves uninstalled very quickly).

A better idea is to use `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` and apply the `(0,+10)` offset to the current position in your own code - I don't know why you're so opposed to using `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`, it just means you need to get the current coordinates first, which is hardly much work.

Comment: I understand. The problem seems to persist whether I use `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` or not, even turning off mouse acceleration didn't solve my problem.
I tried setting my mouse coordinate to the same position I get via `GetCursorPos` and it's still a few pixels off

Comment: @RedChalk What is your display DPI? Do you have any third-party mouse software installed (e.g. Logitech Gaming Software, Razer, etc?)

Comment: Scale is set to 100% with 1920x1080 resolution and no I don't have any third party mouse software installed

Comment: Turns out mouse acceleration was the case. It seems turning it off via control panel didn't actually do anything, doing it via code however fixed it.

Comment: @RedChalk The `mouse_event()` documentation says "*An application obtains and sets these [acceleration] values with the `SystemParametersInfo()` function*" - have you tried that yet? See `SPI_GETMOUSE` - "*Retrieves the two mouse threshold values and the mouse acceleration.*" The `mouse_event()` documentation describes in detail exactly how acceleration affects relative mouse positioning (a little more detail then what the `MOUSEINPUT` documentation offers for `SendInput()`). Try reading the acceleration values and adjust your x,y positions accordingly to get the result you want.

Comment: @Dai the only issue with `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` is that it is not actually *absolute*, it is *normalized*, so there is some calculation work that has to be done to provide x,y coordinates, so the end result could still drift a few pixels.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you provide more details about that normalization process?

Comment: @Dai per the `mouse_event()` and `MOUSEINPUT` docs: "*If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain **normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535**. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface; coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner. In a multimonitor system, the coordinates map to the primary monitor.*" This means when using `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`, you will have to set `mi.dx = (x * 65535) / (screen width);` and `mi.dy = (y * 65535) / (screen height);`